# How to debug invalid data in MySQL utf8mb4 column in Etherpad Lite database

Tags: mysql, utf-8, utf8mb4, invalid-characters, etherpad

We're running Etherpad Lite and we're trying to migrate database from MySQL to PostgreSQL.

MySQL database 'value' column is of type utf8mb4. However, around 10% of all rows contain value that is in fact encoded in Windows-1252 or ISO-8859-15 instead of UTF-8. How is this possible? Does not MySQL validate the UTF-8 before entering it into the column?

PostgreSQL cannot accept the invalid values during migration because it does validate the data and hits e.g. raw byte 0xE4 (ISO-8859-15: `ä`) which should be encoded as byte sequence 0xC3 0xA4 in UTF-8.

Is this a known "feature" of MySQL? Is there any way to always get real UTF-8 from `utf8mb4` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No solution is known.** This is probably a bug in MySQL which should disallow storing non-UTF-8 data in case *client* connnection and *column type* are both utf8mb4.

I no longer use MySQL for anything so I haven't bothered to try to figure this bug any more. Nowadays, I'm using PostgreSQL for everything instead.

Answer (score 0):

If

- you say the *client* is using `latin1` (etc), and
- you say the *column* is utf8 (or utf8mb4), and
- you provide hex `E4`

Then all is well.  The `E4` will be converted during the `INSERT` into `C3A4` and that is what is stored.  Do `SELECT HEX(...) ...` to verify.

If

- you say the *client* is using utf8 (or utf8mb4), and
- you say the *column* is utf8 (or utf8mb4), and
- you provide hex `C3A4`

Again, all is well.  The `C3A4` goes directly into the table.

Here's a messy case:

If

- you say the *client* is using `latin1`, and
- you say the *column* is utf8 (or utf8mb4), and
- *but* you provide hex `C3A4`

Then, MySQL is obligated to convert *two* characters (C3 and A4) into utf8, yielding `C383C2A4`.  I call this "double encoding".

Follow the Best Practice in [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) and use its suggested way to test the data.  Then come back with more details.

Probably the only way for 10% of the data to be mis-interpreted is for 10% of the data to be encoded differently.  So, please provide hex for a 10% example and for a 90% example.  And provide the hex in the client before inserting and in the table after it is inserted.

Comment: I have a case where client says `set names utf8` and database column is of type `utf8mb4` and `SELECT` still returns strings containing raw byte `\xE4` in place of `ä` or U+00E4. Note that UTF-8 should encode that character as `\xC3\xA4`. The data is originally inputted by node.js service in case that matters.

Comment: Then you have "lied" about the bytes being utf8.  Hex `E4` is latin1.  `U+00E4` may look similar, but that is _unicode_, not latin1, nor utf8.  Saying `set names utf8` is saying that the _client_ will have hex `C3A4` for `ä`.

Comment: I agree that plain `0xE4` should not appear in UTF-8 string. However, Etherpad Lite (running on node.js) will sometimes emit raw Windows-1252 characters in the middle of UTF-8 strings (I think this is a bug in node.js or Etherpad Lite) and MySQL will happily store such string in the MyISAM table. If MySQL did thrown exception instead of accepting such invalid string I would not be asking this question.

Comment: UTF-8 string may include byte `0xE4` if it's followed by other bytes with 8th bit set. For example, U+4494 is byte sequence `0xE4 0x92 0x94`.

Comment: I have no idea how to reproduce the problem (insert the data to database) but the fact is that MySQL is returning part of the data from database with Windows-1252 encoding even though the connection is set to UTF-8 and database column type is `utf8mb4`.